# MS Access - [SQL] Filter list via Searchbar with LIKE statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

On my MS Access form I've created a textbox with a button to search or filter a list by the entered keyword.

The first thing I tried was this:

```
Private Sub search_Click()

Dim mssql as String
Dim keyword as String

Me.searchbar.SetFocus
keyword = Me.searchbar.Text

mssql = " SELECT ID, LastName, GivenName FROM tNames WHERE LastName = " & Chr(34) & keyword & Chr(34) & ";"
Me.list_1.RowSource = mssql
Me.list_1.Requery


End Sub
```

The search function worked fine but I wanted something more flexible. So I tried to implement the LIKE statement.

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to properly implement the LIKE variable into my code.

I would try something like this, without any success:

```
mssql = " SELECT ID, LastName, GivenName FROM tNames WHERE LastName LIKE "% & keyword & %";"
```

It's really confusing to me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the * wildcard and apostrophe delimiters.

`"SELECT ID, LastName, GivenName FROM tNames WHERE LastName LIKE '*" & keyword & "*';"`

However, could just put SQL statement directly in the RowSource property in combobox design with:

`SELECT ID, LastName, GivenName FROM tNames WHERE LastName LIKE "*" & [searchbar] & "*";`

Then the code only needs to Requery the combobox.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: There are several row sources which you can trigger by clicking different buttons. Adding this code directly into the rowsource property isn't an option for me. But thanks anyway

Comment: Weird, now it works like you wrote it in the firat code. Thanks!